# Bad Authentication data on twitter api with http status 200

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using a twitter library in javascript called codebird-js. I provided my consumer key and token to tweet however I get back code 215 with the http status 200. On the twitter website it says that you usually get this code with http 400 so I dont know the meaning of this. This is the sample code, can anyone give me pointers on why I am getting this error:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var cb = new Codebird;
            cb.setConsumerKey('xxx','xxx');
            cb.setToken('xxx', 'xxx');

            var params = {
                status: "im trying"
            };
            cb.__call(
                    "statuses_update",
                    params,
                    function (reply) {
                        console.log(reply);  
                    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

215 means

Bad authentication data - Typically sent with 1.1 responses with HTTP code 400. The method requires authentication but it was not presented or was wholly invalid.

source : https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes

Comment: Yes I understand, but as you can see on the provided code, all the authentication is provided. I have checked multiple times and the keys/tokens match what twitter provided for me. So I do not know the problem here

Comment: ok, here's what I did. the token you used is not the one you need to use. So after you set the token like you did, call the "oauth2_token" method as shown in their documentation. That will give you a bearer token you can then use for further methods.

Comment: But isnt it mentioned on https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only that this is used for application-only-authentication(does not allow you to tweet)? I just want single-user authentication because I only want to tweet to my account.

Comment: even after calling oauth2_token, i am not able to get public timeline of user